# Managing Visual Studio solutions and lots of common .Net libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shared-libraries

I have been using Java for quite a while and I am fairly new to C#.

I now work in a team which uses lots and lots of common libraries/DLLs (predominantly .Net).

I work on a few (Visual Studio) projects, all of which needs the common libraries, what is a common practice with Visual Studio for both Release and Debug modes?

For Debug Configuration Mode (CM), my colleague advised me to put all the libraries into a folder (call this L) then set "Startup" folder to L. But there is no such concept for Release CM. So, I need to either a) copy the content of L to executable output path or b) set the output path of the project to L. Neither seems like a clean solution, what do you advise?

Is there something similar to classpath in Java?

Answer (score 1):

It is very common to add common .dlls/references to a 'Library' project or as solution items.  Reference these .dll's from your projects and they will be copied to the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my shop we have a 'lib' folder created inside the solution's folder. Inside the lib folder there's a copy of each DLL referenced by the solution; so VS copies the referenced DLLs to the output directory when building or executing the solution. It also allows you to have different versions of the same DLLs for different solutions, if you have that need (although I don't recommend it).

Comment: Is there is any way for me to not have to copy any reference DLL around at all without using GAC? I want to have one and only one copy of DLLs in a central location, say %LIB_DIR% pointing to C:\Lib (for both development and production)... Does any one does this?

Comment: Yeah, you could also do that. But without using GAC, I don't think there's an equivalent in C# to Java's ClassPath.